# TableView Cell alpha trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my project I have tableview controller with Static Cells.
I need to set alpha for cells.
I do it with this code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setAlpha:0.25f];
}
```

But my problem is that `[cell setAlpha: 0.25f]` also affects the textLabel. 
Please, help, how can I fix it?

Comment: You want to change the alpha of the `contentView`, `backgroundView` of cell?

Comment: I want to change alpha of the cell's background.

Comment: Try: `[[cell backgroundView] setAlpha:0.25];`

Comment: ouh(( nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the background colour of your cell:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.25.f];
```

This will set your cell background colour to white, and its alpha to 0.25.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is not solve my problem at all, but it help me to make somthing closer to that what I want. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

The textLabel is a subview of your cell, so it's normal that if you set the cell alpha, its subviews are impacted to. The way you can solved this is by making a custom cell where the text label won't be a subview of your background view (the one you want to set an alpha on) so it's not impacted by the alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
// i do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath
cell.contentView.alpha = 0;
```

Comment: Why do you want to set alpha to this cell? What do you want the cell look like? I think you can edit more information about your cell which you want.